# Need help using increments and displaying in a textbox

Tags: javascript

We need to have a textbox where you enter a number, hit a button, and it increments by `1`, while staying in the same text box. Here is the code I have so far:

```
<form action=#>
    <p>
        Current Count...<input type="text" id="txtCounter" value="0">
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="button" value="Increment Count" id="btnIncrement" onclick="btnIncrement_onclick()">
        <input type="reset">
    </p>
</form>
<noscript>This website requires JavaScript to be enabled.</noscript>
```

*JavaScript:*

```
function btnIncrement_onclick() {
    // get textbox and assign to a variable
    var countTextbox = document.getElementById("txtCounter");
    var txtCounterData = txtCounter.value;
    var countTextbox.value = 0++;
}
```

If someone could explain to me how to do it not just give me the answer. I don't know why I'm having such a hard time with this.

Comment: Java `=/=` JavaScript

Comment: Why this line `var txtCounterData = txtCounter.value;`.

Comment: `txtCounter.value` is the issue - you named the variable `countTextBox` in the line above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following simple code :

```js
function btnIncrement_onclick()
{
    //asign the textbox to variable
    var textbox = document.getElementById("txtCounter");

    //Get the value of textbox and add 1 then update the textbox
    textbox.value = parseInt(textbox.value)+1;
}
```

```html
<form action=#>
    <p>
        Current Count...<input type="text" id="txtCounter" value="0">
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="button" value="Increment Count" id="btnIncrement" onclick="btnIncrement_onclick()">
        <input type="reset">
    </p>
</form>
<noscript>This website requires JavaScript to be enabled.</noscript>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Take a look at [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith he don't have yet enough reputation to voteup.

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML:

In your html you had a `onclick="btnIncrement_onclick()"` and that means every click will triggers your function.

In your JS:

```
function btnIncrement_onclick() {
    // Named as countTextbox you input. sou we can use it later.
    var countTextbox = document.getElementById("txtCounter");

    // Get the current value attribute of it, initialy 0.
    var txtCounterData = txtCounter.value;

    // The line above is not being used. but you can check it with a console.log like this:
    console.log(txtCounterData);

    // Now you are calling again your input and changing his value attribute. this ++  means a increment. so we are increasing +1;
    countTextbox.value++;
}
```

You should read more about increment and operators and DOM (the way whe select the tag by id, and again selected his attribute).

Sorry didn't found a good source in english.